# Как удалить элемент из многомерного массива?

Tags: php, массивы

```
$myarr = array(1) {
    [0]=> array(5) { 
        [0]=> array(4) {
            ["label"]=> string(50) "Главная" ["link"]=> string(25) "https://my.site/" ["title"]=> string(50) "Главная" ["type"]=> string(9) "blog_home"
        } 

        [1]=> array(4) {
            ["label"]=> string(27) "Блог" ["link"]=> string(41) "https://my.site/" ["title"]=> string(27) "Блог" ["type"]=> string(7) "kb_home"
        } 

        [2]=> array(4) {
            ["label"]=> string(30) "Авто" ["link"]=> string(49) "https://my.site/" ["title"]=> string(76) "Просмотреть все записи в Авто" ["type"]=> string(6) "kb_tax"
        } 

        [3]=> array(4) {
            ["label"]=> string(39) "Природа" ["link"]=> string(51) "https://my.site/" ["title"]=> string(85) "Просмотреть все записи в Природа" ["type"]=> string(6) "kb_tax"
        } 

        [4]=> array(4) {
            ["label"]=> string(60) "Новости" ["link"]=> string(58) "https://my.site/" ["title"]=> string(60) "Новости" ["type"]=> string(15) "kb_current_page"
        }
    }
}
```

Нужно удалить

```
[1]=> array(4) {
    ["label"]=> string(27) "Блог" ["link"]=> string(41) "https://my.site/" ["title"]=> string(27) "Блог" ["type"]=> string(7) "kb_home"
}
```

Пробовал так

```
<?php array_slice($myarr, 1);?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
unset($myarr[0][1]);
```

Функция `unset` удалит элемент.

Comment: @eanmos да он удаляет, но тогда последовательность [0] [2] [3] [4], а мне нужно чтобы следующая строчка была c ключем [1]=> array(4) {
            ["label"]=> string(30) "Авто" ["link"]=> string(49) "https://my.site/" ["title"]=> string(76) "Просмотреть все записи в Авто" ["type"]=> string(6) "kb_tax"
        }

Answer (score 0):

Удалить элемент, после - переиндесировать значения.

```
unset($myarr[0][1]);
$myarr[0] = array_values($myarr[0]);
```